# In a PowerShell module, using Start-Transcript in an exported function, changes the return value?

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I hope someone can assist with this issue.
I've created a logger for some work purpose, which I've made as a PS Module.
The logger works fine, however just learned about the `Start-Transcript` and thought I'd incorporate this into my module, to log everything (including errors and other information) in a runtimelog.

The module contains a PS Class and an exported function. (see https://github.com/Ostekages/Powershell_logger/blob/main/logger.psm1)

However, here's where I encounter an issue.

When creating an instance of the class, normally it is of `TypeName: Logger`

But when the `Start-Transcript` is in the exported function, it is now a `TypeName: System.String`

For reference, this is the two exported functions, with or without start-transcript:

```
function UseLogger ($name, $path) {
    return [Logger]::New($name,$path)
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function UseLogger
```

```
function UseLogger ($name, $path) {
    Start-Transcript -Path "$Path" -Append -NoClobber
    return [Logger]::New($name,$path)
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function UseLogger
```

My issue is that the methods from the class, don't work, and just reports `No method "log" on type [System.String]`

Any information is appreciated greatly!

Regards
Oste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript) outputs a string, suppress it to get only the logger instance:

```
function UseLogger ($name, $path) {
    Start-Transcript -Path "$Path" -Append -NoClobber |Out-Null
    return [Logger]::New($name,$path)
}
```